# Python Selenium new tab Microsoft edge

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

So I want to automate Microsoft edge using the python selenium module I wanted to use chrome but I don't know why whenever I open chrome on my pc my pc automatically shuts down so I using Microsoft edge. I figured out how to make a driver with Microsoft edge and how to open a website using Microsoft edge but my question is how to display links in a new tab:

To understand my question here is some code:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions


class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
       options = EdgeOptions()
       options.use_chromium = True
       self.driver = Edge(options=options)

    def go_to_link(self, *url):
        for i in url:
            self.driver.get(i)

    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def quit(self):
        self.driver.quit()

links = ["https://www.google.co.in/", "https://www.youtube.com/", "https://stackoverflow.com/"]
Driver = Driver()
Driver.go_to_link(*links)
Driver.quit()
```

SO I want each link to be displayed in a new tab in Microsoft edge can anyone help me with how to do it?

I would really appreciate it if anyone helps if they can't it's still fine.

Comment: `links` is a list. Do you want to open in different tabs  ?

Comment: yes i want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop into all the links like below :

```
links = ["https://www.google.co.in/", "https://www.youtube.com/", "https://stackoverflow.com/"]
number_of_tabs = len(links)
count = 1
for link in links :
  driver.get(link)
  windows_before = driver.current_window_handle
  driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
  #WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(number_of_tabs))
  new_window = driver.window_handles[count]
  count = count + 1
  driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
  sleep(3)
```

Comment: But does this make it come in a new tab

Comment: @Rohit12345 : wait working on it. Is it reloading in the same tab ?

Comment: @Rohit12345  : try out the new code it works for me ! you can change `driver` with `self.driver`

Comment: OK  i am not getting why for me sleep(3) is giving an error can you say what i have to write to make it applicable for the class Driver

Comment: @Rohit12345 : try with `time.sleep(3)` instead

Comment: Ok so i imported the time module i know what time.sleep() does

Comment: But can you explain me how you made the new tab

Comment: using `driver.execute_script("window.open('');")` it will open a new tab with no URL and when in the next run `driver.get(link)` is called it will pick up the link from list. All we have to make sure is that we switch to new tab as soon as it is opened

Comment: So that opens a new tab

Comment: So if i write driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.youtube.com');") what does that do

Comment: if you don't have any `driver.get()` before it would launch in then same tab